# Adding an integer to the end of a linked list

Tags: java

I am trying to add an array of `Integer` to the end of a linked list. My code adds the first integer and then when it reads the second integer it just replaces the previous number. The list does not create a new node for the second item and so on which then gets a null pointer exception. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Integer[] values  = { 0,  10,  20,  30,  40,  50,  60,  70,  80,  90};
```

Here is my method

```
  public boolean addAll(Integer [] c)
  {
      Node cur = this.head;
      if(cur != null)
      {
         cur = cur.next;     
      }

      int i = 0;   
      for(; i < c.length; i++)
      {           
         if(cur == null)
         {
            cur = add(c[i]);
         }
         else
         {
           cur = cur.next;
           cur.next = add(c[i]);
         }

      }     

      size++; 
      return true;
 }
```

These are the nodes I am given to work with

```
  protected Node ( Comparable data )
  {
     this.data = data;
     this.next = null;
  }// end constructor


  protected Node ( Comparable data, Node next )
  {
     this.data = data;
     this.next = next;
  }// end constructor
```

So what I am confused about is how would I be able to pass in an array of integers with the two given nodes. That's where I am stuck. If I was to do something like this cur.next = new Node(add(c[i])); It would not work since the parameter does not match with either of those nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
public static Node addLast(Node n, Object obj) {
   Node node = n;

   while ((n.next != null)) {
       n = n.next;
   }

   n.next = new Node(obj, null);
   return node;
}
```

Unfortunately you have to loop it through to find out the last item and then insert it.

Comment: This won't work since I have to pass in an Integer [] c as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you keep a pointer to the last node in your linked list. This massively speeds up most of your operations.

```
public void add (Integer[] toAdd) {
  int x;

  for (x=0; x < x.Length ;x++) {
    this.last.next = new Node(toAdd[x]);
    this.last = last.next;
  }

  last.next = null;
}
```

Comment: This would probably work but with the given Node types I wouldn't be able to pass in an Integer []  into the new Node.